# fourier series vs function plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib

i have a function that is defined as p(t) =sin(t/k) from 0<t<2pi*k and p(t)=0 from 2pi*k<t<T. And i have to approximate how many fourier coefficients i have to use to get a reasnoble result. Don´t know how to plot the fourier series but the first bit to get the fourier coefficients seems to work. Please give me tips.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import sympy as smp

from scipy.integrate import quad

#the function
def x(t, k):
    return np.sin(t/k)

#getting the fourier coefficients
def get_x_FT(x, n, k, T):
    x_FT_integrand_real = lambda t: np.real(x(t, k)*np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*(n/T)*t))
    x_FT_integrand_comp = lambda t: np.imag(x(t, k)*np.exp(-2*np.pi*1j*(n/T)*t))
    x_FT_real = quad(x_FT_integrand_real, 0, 2*np.pi*T/30)[0]
    x_FT_comp = quad(x_FT_integrand_comp, 0, 2*np.pi*T/30)[0]
    return x_FT_real + 1j*x_FT_comp

#multiplying coefficients by explonential to get functions
def f(x, N,T):
   f = np.array([2*get_x_FT(i)*np.exp(1j*2*i*np.pi*x/T) for i in range(-N,N+1)])
   return f.sum()
```